# silly confusion about subgroup proof: $< g,h> = \{g^r h^s : r, s \in Z\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

Could someone help me understand this? It says certainly $<g,h> \supseteq \{g^r h^s : r, s \in Z\}$ which i understand. But now arent we suppose to show that $<g,h> \subseteq \{g^r h^s : r, s \in Z\}$? I dont understand what the note is saying. It is proving that $\{g^r h^s\}$ is a subgroup of G. I dont understand why?

And then same with proposition97 proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\langle g,h \rangle$ is the smallest subgroup containing both $g$ and $h$ (more formally, it's the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing $g,h$). So if you show that $\{g^rh^s : r,s \in \mathbb Z\}$ is a subgroup, it is by definition contained in $\langle g,h \rangle$ and hence you have equality.

If you understand why Example 95 makes sense now, Proposition 97 follows by the exact same reasoning.